# wp_enqueue_script В одном месте работает, а в другом нет

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Кто-то может подсказать, почему один и тот же код на внутренних страницах работает, а на главной нет? При этом, стили подключаются без проблем.

```
    function g() {
        return get_template_directory_uri();
    }

if(is_front_page()) {
    wp_enqueue_style('reset', g() . '/assets/css/reset.css', false, NULL, 'all'); // работает
    wp_enqueue_style('custom', g() . '/assets/css/front/main.css', false, NULL, 'all');  // работает

    wp_register_script('maa', g() . '/assets/js/front/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true); //не работает

    wp_enqueue_script('maa'); //не работает
}

if (!is_front_page()) {  
    // тут всё работает работает
    wp_register_script('lg', g() . '/assets/js/lightgallery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('sa','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10', array( 'jquery' ), '', true);

    wp_register_script('mainjs', g() . '/assets/js/main.js',array( 'jquery' ), '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('lg');
    wp_enqueue_script('mainjs');

}
```

Comment: Что в консоли браузера? 404?

Answer (score 0):

`is_front_page()` в первом условии вы проверяете на что отображается главная статичная страница
`!is_front_page()` а во втором условии вы проверяете на что отображается любая другая страница

Comment: Да, так и задумано. Я просто привёл в пример, что для страниц не главных отрабатывает идентичный код, но в другой папке. А для фронта этот же код не работает. Но стили работают

Comment: скрипт может не подключится если совпадает идентификатор либо если не подключается файл из зависимостей

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что у меня абсолютно разный вид внутренних страниц от главной и у меня везде стоят проверки на фронт. Так и я засунул `wp_footer`  в условие, которое срабатывает везде, кроме главной. А со стилями было правильно.

Решение - вынести

```
<?php } // закрываем if (!is_front_page()) {
wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```